# How to get only some certain values from pytorch dataset __getitem__, while using dataloader

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I want to get only some certain 'idx'es from `__getitem__` of a pytorch customDataset. for i.e. I want only `1 5 8 11` get passed as `idx` to `__getitem__` of dataset, while I wrap a dataloader to that custom dataset.

or in other words, assume I must exactly have `print(idx)` at the line after `def __getitem__(self, idx):`

what can I do, so the `print(idx)`, prints

```
1
5
8
11
```

I mean only values in indexes get passed to the `__getitem__`
but right now it prints

```
0
1
2
3
```

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, indexes):
        self.data = data
        self.indexes = indexes

    def __len__(self):
        if self.indexes is None:
            return len(self.data)
        return len(self.indexes)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        print(idx)
        return 1
custom_dataset = CustomDataset([i for i in range(20)], [1,5,8,11])
custom_dataloader = DataLoader(custom_dataset, batch_size=64)
for batch in custom_dataloader:
    pass
```

as it is obvious, setting the `self.indexes=[1, 5, 8, 11]` doesnt do my request.

first priority is to have some straight way, like with setting some attribute in the customDataset if possible, and not using extra objects like samplers.

note I have problem with samplers, which I may ask on another question. also the sampler, removes the freedom to use `shuffle=True`. so the straight way is more prefered way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have data of length 20 but you want to limit usage to a subset of indices which has the length four in this case.

Also, you want to wrap this in a DataLoader. I really dont think this is something you should do. The Dataset object is made for accessing specific indices and therefore should return the data at the requested without altering it internally to output something else.

So you should either instantiate the Dataset class only with the allowed data which can be iterated in a sequentiel fashion by the loader and its default sampler, or prevent the loader to access the forbidden indices in the first place by implementing a default sampler (which you want to avoid). Therefore I suggest the following minimal change to your code...

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, indexes=None):
        self.data = data
        self.indexes = indexes

    def __len__(self):
        if self.indexes is None:
            return len(self.data)
        return len(self.indexes)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        print("index not the same as before:", idx)
        return data[idx]

#all data
data = np.array([i for i in range(20)]]
#allowed indices
allowed = [1,5,8,11]
# limit data
data = data[allowed]

custom_dataset = CustomDataset(data)
custom_dataloader = DataLoader(custom_dataset, batch_size=64)
for batch in custom_dataloader:
    pass
```

Comment: no, I want my data to be kept!!!!

Comment: assume I want to get next 5 rows of data, in the `__getitem__`, so I should have all of my data and be able to pass only some idxes to `__getitem__` because the other indices, may not have full next 5 data items.

Comment: sorry but I still don't understand the problem. Maybe try to explain WHAT your are trying to do instead of HOW you try to achieve it? Maybe there are other ways to go?

Comment: I want to limit the idxes passed to `__getitem__(self, idx)`(==selectedIndexes), the inner steps would raise an error, if other idx, than those selectedIndexes are passed.
it is all about the inner steps of `__getitem__` would have problem.